# Openvms dhcp server

Tags: dhcp, openvms

Ok so I have OpenVMS VAX running under simh. I am attempting to setup the dhcp server, but I'm unclear on some of the config. I tried following along with the online docs, but no go. My clients aren't getting dhcp leases. Any help is appreciated, I'm still learning OpenVMS. My config looks like this:

### DHCPAP:

```
subnet1:\
    :tc=.global:\
    :nw=192.168.1.0:\
    :gw=192.168.1.1:\
    :sm=255.255.255.0:\
    :dn=LOCALDOMAIN:\
    :ds=192.168.1.1:\
    :lt=10080:
```

### NETS:

192.168.1.10-192.168.1.50

### NETMASK:

192.168.1.0     255.255.255.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a recent version of OpenVMS and TCPIP, you can set it up with

`$ SYS$STARTUP:@TCPIP$CONFIG`

then you can launch it

`@sys$startup:TCPIP$DHCP_STARTUP.COM`

and you should have a DHCP server

see this doc for configuring it

http://h41379.www4.hpe.com/doc/732final/6526/6526pro_018.html

to stop it

`$ @SYS$STARTUP:TCPIP$DHCP_SHUTDOWN.COM`

Comment: Thanks, I was missing the file owner IP in NETS. Once I got that in it works.

Answer (score 1):

I am running on a 192.168.1.x/24 network. In case anyone else runs into this issue, my config is:

### DHCPCAP

```
subnet1:\
    :tc=.global:\
    :nw=192.168.1.0:\
    :gw=192.168.1.1:\
    :sm=255.255.255.0:\
    :dn=LOCALDOMAIN:\
    :ds=8.8.8.8:\
    :lt=10080:
```

### NETS

```
*(192.168.1.250 is the dhcp server/OpenVMS ip, 192.168.1.30-192.168.1.50 is the pool range.)*

192.168.1.0 192.168.1.250 192.168.1.30-192.168.1.50
```

### Netmasks

192.168.1.0     255.255.255.0